# Maintain PUB/SUB communication

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, publish-subscribe, marionette, backbone-events

What is the best practise to maintain complex structure using Pub/Sub to communicate between modules?

I finished up my last project with a lot of module that are nicely decoupled (maybe even “overdecoupled”). But if want to debug something or change event subscriptions and publishes, a lot of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is involved to find all code parts interrested in specific event. Is there any pattern for better event based communication management? I used Marionette and its `EventAggregator` as pub/sub.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the exact use case for the **RequestResponse** object.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.requestresponse.md

Handler:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.reqres.setHandler("foo", function(bar){
  return bar + "-quux";
});
```

Request:

```
App.request("foo", "baz"); // => returns "baz-quux"
```